# Are 8-Zone Wiring Centers Compatible With Smart Thermostats?

Tags: thermostat, radiant-heating, zoned-heating, floorheating, iot

I'm looking at various wiring centers for gas boiler heating and I'm wondering if they're compatible with the major smart thermostats, such as Nest, Hive, and Honeywell.

**Wiring Centers:**

- Reliance: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Reliance-Zone-Wiring-Centre-Underfloor/dp/B00HNNBUQK
- Heatmiser: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Heatmiser-UH8-230v-Wiring-Centre/dp/B01N9H4YHV
- Waterline: https://www.amazon.co.uk/CONTROLLER-UNDERFLOOR-HEATING-8-ZONES/
- Salus: https://www.amazon.co.uk/KL08NSB-Wiring-Underfloor-Heating-Communication/dp/B07KSYBGCT

I'm wondering if these wiring centers only work with the specific thermostats of the manufacturer, or are they "universal" and they can work with other thermostats. I haven't been able to verify this. Does anybody know the answer?

Follow-up: if they are, then how does the thermostat control all 8 zones? Any reference materials out there?

**Update**:

Manufacturer product info (as best as I could find them):

- Reliance: N/A
- Heatmiser: https://www.heatmiser.com/en/central-wiring-centres/
- Waterline: N/A
- Salus: https://salus-controls.com/files/KL08NSB-QG-EN-v001.pdf

Comment: Can you post manufacturer's links for your products, not just Amazon links? Amazon tends to bury important things (like the actual model number of products)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I added the info as best as I could find it.